# Adding text input box to an HTML page using Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and most likely I am missing something very simple.
Anyway, this is my questions:

I try to add an empty input box to an HTML page the following way ...

```
    ...

    var view = Ember.View.create({
          templateName: 'say-hello',
    });
    view.append();

    ...

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
        {{view App.TextField}}
    </script>
```

However I don't get the input box.
Feedback is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for asking, absent-mindedness be damned. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ember.TextField` instead of `App.TextField`

Comment: Thanks Roy! I just realized that myself and I was about to admit how absent minded I was and then I saw your reply.